# How to send the web page values to the emai

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

Using ASP.Net, VB.Net

In my web page, i have the textbox values

when i press the send button the textbox value automatically send to email address...

How to do that...

Need Code Help

Comment: you have been a member of this site for over a year: by now you should have realised that a question like this contains insufficient information to help you. If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question. Your question is broad and tells us nothing about which specific problems you are facing. How about fixing up the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code sample is as follow:

```
Dim oMsg As System.Web.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Web.Mail.MailMessage()
oMsg.From = "noone@nobody.com"
oMsg.To = "someone@somewhere.com"
oMsg.Subject = "Email with Attachment Demo"
oMsg.Body = "This is the main body of the email"
Dim oAttch As MailAttachment = New MailAttachment("C:\myattachment.zip")
oMsg.Attachments.Add(oAttch)
SmtpMail.Send(oMsg)
```

You can also find an example ;on the following link:

http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/Email.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx